# javascript flot threshold for dynamic data value

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

Here is my plot data

```
var data = [{
                data: [[4, 80], [8, 50], [9, 130]],
                color: "rgb(30, 180, 20)",
                threshold: {
                    below: 100,
                    color: "rgb(200, 20, 30)"
                }
            }]
        var bar = $.plot("#placeholder", data);
```

and if i change the value of data in a  button click like

```
     data= [[4, 130], [8, 50], [9, 130]];
     bar.setData([data]);
              bar.draw();

              });
```

The treshold value didnt work , if there is a way to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating the data correctly.  You are initially giving flot a series object with threshold settings, when you `setData` though, you are giving it an array without those settings.

Do this instead to preserve your series options:

```
someData = somePlot.getData();
someData[0].data = [[4, 130], [8, 50], [9, 130]];
somePlot.setData(someData);
somePlot.draw();
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFnFlPVPC58rMlN8kW9u?p=preview).

**EDITS**

If you don't like the `getData` call, leave your master data variable in scope and update that as @Raidri hinted at:

```
var masterData = [{
            data: [[4, 80], [8, 50], [9, 130]],
            color: "rgb(30, 180, 20)",
            threshold: {
                below: 100,
                color: "rgb(200, 20, 30)"
            }
        }]

 // later ...

 masterData[0].data = [[4, 130], [8, 50], [9, 130]];
 somePlot.setData(masterData);
 somePlot.draw();
```

The important part is to leave your threshold series options intact in the `setData` call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `bar.setupGrid()` before the `bar.draw()`?

If that doesn't help, you make a complete new plot:

```
data[0].data = [[4, 130], [8, 50], [9, 130]];
bar = $.plot("#placeholder", data)
```

Comment: bar.setupGrid() not working for me, any other way without creating new plot?

Comment: It should work without creating a new plot, so there thems to be a bug in the threshold plugin. Unless you find the bug, the only way would be to create a new plot.